# Is it possible to encode a struct to calldata when calling another function?

Tags: solidity, evm, struct, calldata

Let's say I have the following struct:

```
struct Price {
    uint value;
}
```

Let's say I have the following function:

```
function isPriceOkay(Price calldata price) public pure returns (bool) {
    return price.value > 10;
}
```

Is it possible to, from another function, encode a memory/storage to calldata when sending it to another function. Such as in:

```
function buy() public view returns (bool) {
    Price memory priceData;
    price.value = 10;
    // Maybe do some encoding here?
    return isPriceOkay(priceData); // <-- I wonder if this is possible (in any way)
}
```

If it is possible, is it possible to do it with nested structs?

Answer (score 0):

You can instantiate a new `Price` inline. Is it your concern?

If yes, the example below demonstrates the syntax for that kind of assignment.

However, you'll need to change the function's `calldata` to `memory`.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.13;

contract Test {

    struct Price {
        uint64 value;
    }
    address private immutable owner;

    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier auth() {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "You are not authorized to call this function");
        _;
    }

    function mint() external payable auth {
        callInnerFunction(Price({
            value: uint64(msg.value)
        }));

        // do something
    }

    function callInnerFunction(Price memory price) internal {

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! My understanding is that when the parameter is calldata, it uses less gas. So my logic was, if I have a function that uses a struct and only reads from it, maybe using it as calldata will require less gas.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to modify calldata. It is read only from within the same transaction.

To create calldata you could make an external call.

```
function isPriceOkay(Price calldata price) external pure returns (bool) {
    return price.value > 10;
}

function buy() public view returns (bool) {
    Price memory priceData;
    priceData.value = 10;
    // Maybe do some encoding here?
    return this.isPriceOkay(priceData);
}
```

You won't be saving anything because you have to pay extra for the external call.